# Difficulty making Strava Iframe Responsive (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile, responsive-design

> UPDATE:
>   The idea behind my attempts so far has been focused on adjusting the iframe container and fixing it based on the intrinsic ratio of the Iframe so that it would then as it responds to change in proportion the contents would also change proportionally. This does not seem to work as some elements of the iframe remain fixed. I would really like to have a responsive Strava Iframe but for some reason cannot figure out to achieve this. I have made a [Codepen Collection](https://codepen.io/collection/DLjNVk/) with current attempts thus far.

I have recently added a shortcode for embedding [Strava](https://www.strava.com) iframes into my Hugo site (academic theme). On the desktop, devices the iframes render properly and appear to be responsive in browsers, yet on mobile devices, this isn't the case.  The issue at hand can be seen on this [webpage](https://www.dylangrimeslarkin.me/post/running/back-at-it/) and my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dylangrimesxo/dylangrimeslarkin). I would be very grateful for any help in resolving this.

I have been trying multiple tried CSS tweaks and variation recommended on the Hugo forum and on other online sources.

Current Shortcode:

```
{{ if and (.Get "id") (.Get "hash") }}
<div class="responsive-object">
<iframe height='405' width='590' frameborder="0" allowtransparency='true' scrolling='no' src="https://www.strava.com/activities/{{ .Get "id" }}/embed/{{ .Get "hash" }}"></iframe>
</div>
{{ end }}
```

Current CSS:

````
.responsive-object iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.responsive-object {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 67.5%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}```

Despite trying to make the iframe container responsive, the same result occurs where it seems responsive on desktop browsers yet not on mobile devices. I am unsure of how to proceed from this point, or if I am missing something.
````

Answer (score 0):

Do you add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

To your `<Head>` ?

If yes imma gonna edit my post with the solution :)

*EDIT*

The best article I've found thus far on creating responsive iframes is [How To Make Responsive Iframes - It's Easy!](https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/).

There are three salient points:

1. Set no attributes in the iframe opening tag, specifically not **width** and **height**
2. Put a div container around the iframe, and use CSS **height: 0**; and then **padding-bottom: nn%;** to give the container a height expressed as the height:width ratio as a percentage.
3. Style the div inline with **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch** and **overflow: auto** which are necessary to handle scrolling on mobile devices and are unstable in CSS.

This code works for me:

// HTML (in an embed block, not a code block)

```
<div class="iframe-container iframe-container-for-wxh-500x350" style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: auto;">

 <iframe src="http://www.targetWebsiteURL.com"> <p style="font-size: 110%;"><em><strong>IFRAME: </strong> There is iframe content being displayed here but your browser version does not support iframes.</em> Please update your browser to its most recent version and try again.</p> </iframe>

 </div>
```

// CSS

```
.iframe-container { position: relative; margin: 5px; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }

.iframe-container-for-wxh-500x350 {
padding: 25px 25px 70% 25px; /* padding-bottom = h/w as a % */
}

.iframe-container iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px inset #7a8b8b;
/* put following styles (necessary for overflow and
scrolling handling) in div container around iframe
because not stable in CSS
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
overflow: auto; */
```

} Use a separate class to style the **padding-bottom** so that, if you have more than one iframe and they are of differing wxh ratios, all you have to do is code a class for each and set **padding-bottom** to the different percentages.

Comment: This method is a marked improvement on anything I have tried so far for mobile, although for some reason it has impacted the desktop iframe which is now dwarfed in size. [link](https://www.dylangrimeslarkin.me/post/running/back-at-it/)

Comment: Do you follow line per line what i've said ? to the .iframe-container change the width and height to what you need

Comment: Yes, I didn't set any iframe attributes in the opening tag. I found the aspect ratio % for the Iframe and added as instructed. Then added the div inline with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch and overflow: auto.

Comment: Looks likes it's back to the drawing board. This Iframe is being particularly pesky. Thanks for your time anyway, appreciated!

Comment: No problem, enjoy your coding ! :)